# Combinging AsyncTask JSON and GridView

Tags: android, gridview, android-asynctask

I'm trying to populate my GridView from an AsyncTask that retreives a JSONList. I have an Array (list) running where I add a few items outside the JSON, and then the returned JSON Data is added to the "list array". This is done, however, it's only processed AFTER the GetView method.

To break it down the steps:

```
class SingleItem
{
    int coverId;
    String titleId;

    SingleItem(int coverId, String titleId) {

        Log.e("SingleItem addition", titleId);

        this.coverId=coverId;
        this.titleId=titleId;
    }
}

public class IssuesGrid extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<SingleItem> list; 

    Context ctx;
    private static String url = "MY_API_URL";
    private static final String issue_id = "issue_id";
    private static final String title = "title";
    JSONArray issues = null;


    public IssuesGrid(Context c) {

        ctx = c;


        list=new ArrayList<SingleItem>();
        int[] coverIds={R.drawable.ic_availableissues,R.drawable.ic_downloadedissues,R.drawable.ic_drawer};

        for (int i=0;i<coverIds.length;i++) {
            SingleItem tempSingleItem = new SingleItem(coverIds[i],"Test");
            list.add(tempSingleItem);
        }

        new JSONParse().execute();


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return list.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    class ViewHolder
    {
        ImageView myCover;
        TextView myTitle;
        ViewHolder(View v)
        {
            myCover = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.issueCover);
            myTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.issueTitle);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        View row=view;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (view==null) 
        {                   
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row= inflater.inflate(R.layout.issue, viewGroup, false);
            holder=new ViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        SingleItem temp = list.get(i);

        holder.myCover.setImageResource(temp.coverId);
        holder.myTitle.setText(temp.titleId);

        return row;
    }


    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

          @Override
            protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

            try {
                issues = json.getJSONArray("issues");

                for (int i = 0; i < issues.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject c = issues.getJSONObject(i);

                    SingleItem tempSingleItem = new SingleItem(c.getInt(issue_id),c.getString(title));
                    list.add(tempSingleItem);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return json;
          }

        }

}
```

Comment: Where are you calling the AsyncTask exactly? It is somewhat hard to follow your code.

Comment: `class IssuesGrid extends BaseAdapter` Please don't call an adapter a grid. Makes your code hard yo read.

Comment: @SlashTag sorry, this one is called inside "issuesGrid", I've added it in there. Edit, I've actually inserted the whole code.

Comment: @greenapps ok, thanks for the tip. will change this once I have it working.